# NotYetImplementedException() while executing QAF feature file having all steps implemented

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, qaf

The below is the feature file:

```
Scenario Outline: Verify logging in navigates user to Home page
    Given I navigate to "<url>" in chrome browser
    And switch control to Login iframe
    When valid "<username>" and "<password>" are entered
    And I click on the Login button
    Then The user is navigated to Home page

Examples: {'datafile' : 'src/main/resources/data/testData.xls', 'sheetName' : 'loginSheet'}
```

All lines from feature file are implemented in Step definitions and while executing the Testng.xml file, I am getting the below error.

**"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: start is not defined"** and I also see something like the below in console.

```
/**
* Auto-generated code snippet by QMetry Automation Framework.
*/
@QAFTestStep(description="I navigate to {0} in chrome browser")
public void iNavigateToInChromeBrowser(String str0){
    //TODO: remove NotYetImplementedException and call test steps
    throw new NotYetImplementedException();
}
```

Please help me in resolving this issue,  I am new to QAF.

Comment: This is resolved. I missed the @QAFTestProvider annotation in the class where all the methods are implemented.

Comment: `@QAFTestProvider` annotation at class only required when you used @Given/When/Then/And annotation from. If you are using `@QAFTestStep` annotation on method  `@QAFTestProvider` is not required on class. May be you have wrong value for `step.provider.pkg`. You can use QAF-BDD-Editors in eclipse which will show error if step not found

Comment: Actually, I didn’t had the @QAFTestStep annotation either. Now it is fine.